# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck SDE solution

Tags: stochastic-calculus, solution-verification, stochastic-integrals

I'm following [this solution](http://planetmath.org/analyticsolutiontoornsteinuhlenbecksde) of

$$dX_t=\kappa(\theta-X_t)\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t \tag1 $$

And the question is whether its solution

$$X_t=\theta+e^{-\kappa(t-s)}(X_s-\theta)+\sigma\int_s^t e^{-\kappa(t-u)}\,dW_u$$

unique? Of course, (1) is a version of a more general SDE, for which uniqueness is established. However, in these particular setting construction of the solution should imply uniqueness. Also for any other solution $X'$ and $D=X-X'$, (1) implies that

$$D_t=-\kappa\int_0^t D_s \, ds, \quad D_0=0,$$

which is just an ordinary DE so that $D(t)=0$ is the unique solution...

Comment: So what is your question...? Whether your reasoning is correct?

Comment: @saz Yes... Did I miss something?

Comment: No, I don't think so ... your reasoning is okay.